# mySQL Multiple Duplicate Handling (Dupes in Dupes)

Tags: mysql, sql

So currently I'm fiddling with something that looks a little like below.

1. It's design is to display things from table attendance, if the student(student) has taken 3 or more instances of the same class (subject).
2. Sometimes teachers(teacher) have substitutes, so we need to know who was teaching when the student acquired the three classes. That is why we need it to display the teacher, as well as the subject & class of 3 or more instances of the same student taking the same class.

   `SELECT i.teacher, i.subject, i.student
   FROM attendance i
   INNER JOIN (
   SELECT subject, student, COUNT(*)
   FROM attendance
   GROUP BY subject, student
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 2) temp
   ON temp.subject = i.subject
   AND temp.student = i.student
   ORDER BY subject, student`

My dilemma is that I already got it to display 3 or more instances, and to display those instances... But I still need to compress it down so multiple instances of the same teacher, student, and subject aren't listed more than once and to be honest I've gotten as far as I can.

And finally a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e27c3b/2/0) of what I'm left with, and trying to remove the duplicates in.

Help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're close, you can either:

- use `SELECT DISTINCT ....` or
- add `SELECT ..... FROM ... JOIN .... GROUP BY i.teacher, i.subject, i.student GROUP BY ...`